# Ignore invalid response header in HttpClient, C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient, .net-5, .net-6.0

I would like to use **HttpClient** to get files with bad but forgivable response headers.
A suggestion has been made at [Ignore invalid response header in HttpClient request #29927](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29927) to use [`socketsHandler.PlaintextStreamFilter`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-5-new-networking-improvements/#socketshttphandler-extension-points).

To me, it seems easier to fork [HttpClient](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/bc7b910144d1f2b62de05540b9df1bb90f3729b9/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs) and add a setting for `useUnsafeHeaderParsing`.

Would you please give a very basic example of how to remove or add headers using [`socketsHandler.PlaintextStreamFilter`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-5-new-networking-improvements/#socketshttphandler-extension-points)?

---

A classical use case for this would be creating a **simple proxy server** where you want to pass all the headers you have received, exactly as you have received them...

> Example of a file with bad response header:
> https://publicadministration.un.org/egovkb/Portals/egovkb/Documents/un/2020-Survey/EgovSurvey2020_Ar.pdf

Comment: What do you mean by `invalid response header`? And how does this affect you? Do you get an exception? Invalid data? What does your code look like? What are the response headers? What prevents you from just reading from the response stream?

Comment: The issue you link to may have nothing to do with your problem. HttpClient has changed a lot in the last 2 years. Right now we have no idea what that problem is. And even if custom handling is required, that should be done in the middleware that actually handles the response. HttpClient is essentially a facade. The actual processing is performed by a pipeline of HttpMessageHandler-derived classes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos An example of an invalid response header is `Strict�?Transport�?Security: max�?age= 31536000; includeSubDomains`, see attached link for example of such a file. The exception I get is `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Received an invalid header name: 'Strict??Transport??Security'.`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The error is thrown at https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/bc7b910144d1f2b62de05540b9df1bb90f3729b9/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnection.cs#L1053